# Way to track the current time with good accuracy

Tags: python, c

I was wondering how to track the current time in C to as much accuracy as possible. In particular, I was wondering if there was a function in C that mimics Python's time.time()?

I found the code below, but it rounds the seconds.

```
#include <time.h>
int main() {
  time_t seconds;
  seconds = time(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use POSIX-compatible system you may try `clock_gettime` function. It returns the current time in nanoseconds.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main() {
    struct timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
    int64_t time_ns = ts.tv_sec * 1000000000LL + ts.tv_nsec;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ts.tv_sec * 1000000000` can reallily overflow a [32-bit `time_t`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).  Suggest `ts.tv_sec * 1000000000LL` or the like to insure at least a 64-bit multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

int main()
{
    clock_t t1, t2;
    t1 = clock();
    float diff = (t1 / 1000000.0F );
    printf("%f",diff);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't assume that `clock` has that resolution. Use `t1 / (float)CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.

Comment: Deep Thought, `double` would make more sense here.  After all, OP wants _good accuracy_, so no need to narrow what `clock_t` may provide.  Also as `diff` might be small, consider `"%g"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `clock` function from `time.h` to measure time with extreme precision.

It'll return the number of clocks elapsed since a reference frame (which is implementation defined but it's related to the program's execution).

```c
#include <time.h>
clock_t now = clock();
```

Now if you want to turn this into an actually understandable time unit, you should divide the result of `clock()` by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`, maybe even multiply it by `1000` to get the result in milliseconds (the precision should be preserved after dividing by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`)

```c
double secs = now / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // Result in seconds
double msecs = secs * 1000; // Result in milliseconds
```

This will work on all systems.

More information on [`clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/clock)

Comment: You need a cast `double secs = (double)now / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;` and also, on some systems you don't get millisecond resolution from `clock()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane In practice, `(double)now` is OK, yet that could narrow the precision of `clock_t`.   A more gentle alternative is `double secs = 1.0 * now / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;` to allow the division to occurs at best precision.

Comment: @chux-Reinstate Monica or `double secs = now / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;` similar to another answer. Though `clock_t`'s precision isn't that great.

Comment: @WeatherVane True in general.  Yet `clock_t` and `time_t` are only specified as some scalar.  It is just that casts can not only widen a type, sometimes they will narrow, so I try to avoid them unless no other good solution exists.  IAC, your point about the weakness of `now / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;` remains valid.